# Methods defined in class Object are instance and class one at the same time

Tags: ruby

How can be described that a method **boo** defined in Object class becomes instance and class one at the same time in class **Foo**?

```
class Foo; end

class Object
  def boo
    'boo method'
  end
end

p Foo.boo # => boo method
p Foo.new.boo # => boo method
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every object is an instance of `Object`. Thus, every object will respond to `boo`.

`Foo` is an object (classes are objects, too), ergo, `Foo` is an instance of `Object` (it is an instance of `Class`, which is a subclass of `Module`, which is a subclass of `Object`).

`Foo.new` is an object (it is an instance of `Foo`, which is a subclass of `Object`).

Since both `Foo` and `Foo.new` are instances of `Object`, both respond to `boo`.

[Note: I am ignoring the existence of `BasicObject`.]

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, keep in mind that the class context and the instance context are entirely different so instance variables are not equivalent.

```
module FooMethods
  def boo
    'boo'
  end
end

class Foo
  extend FooMethods
  include FooMethods
end
```

This deliberately imports the mixin at both the class level via `extend` and instance level via `include`.

Comment: This behavior is one I bumped into accidentally. So I was expecting that boo method became instance method in Foo class.

Comment: If you want to patch Object, which is usually a bad idea, you'll have to patch Class, too.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps forwarding the method to `self` is an option?

```
require 'forwardable'

class Foo
  extend Forwardable

  def self.boo
    'boo method'
  end

  def_delegator self, :boo
end

Foo.boo
#=> "boo method"

Foo.new.boo
#=> "boo method"
```

Comment: The behavior described in my original question is in place without a patching Object with Forwardable. So I'm curious how to describe it rather than achieve :)